# Get Data and Map to Controls from Combobox Selected Value C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

I am trying to get required data into controls when i select specific Student Name from a combobox. i am using SelectedValueChanged event for this and the valuemember for that combobox in order to populate it with required data.

```
StudentsNamesComboBox.DisplayMember = "StudentName";
StudentsNamesComboBox.ValueMember = "SectionId";
```

here the studentnameCombobox has a different value from the parameter value required to get specific record from database using storedprocedure.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmissionNumber", Convert.ToInt16(StudentsNamesComboBox.SelectedValue));
```

the problem i am facing is that i can't get the required parameter value (@AdmissionNumber) from the selected name in the studentNamesCombox.
any idea how to get the required parameter value without changing the studentNamesCombox valuemember? any other way around? because changing vlauemember will affect the whole functionality.
Regards

Comment: how are you populating the combobox?

Comment: Admission number is no where connected to combobox in your code. Do you want to get the admission number for the selected student and then pass it to the command?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yeah exactly. see the StudentName Combobx is popluated when i select a value from another combobox named SectionsComboBox therefore i used sectionId as valuemember in order to get all students from that particular section. but to get the data of selected students i need AdmissionNum which not connected to the StudentName ComboBox. So now i want the AdmissionNum of the selected student and pass its value as a parameter value to get all the required data.

Comment: I updated my answer below based on your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are populating StudentName combobox, why don't you set the ValueMember of that combobox to "AdmissionNumber".

You do not need SectionI of the student in that combobox. SectionId is already available in the other combobox. In StudentName combobox all the items have same sectionId. Correct me if my assumption is wrong.

This way ComboBox.SelectedValue will give the value associated with the selected item which in your case will be "AdmissionNumber".

To get the name of the selected student you need to use ComboBox.SelectedItem.Text. That will give the Selected StudentName in your case.

Comment: Thanks mate. The first half is actually the right answer in my case and worked for me.  Cheers